# Ember - How to add/remove elements from an array property on controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

Given a controller in ember:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  stringProp: "",
  arrayProp: []
});
```

You can, for example, set the string property with `this.set('stringProp', "Blah blah")`. But that is overriding. What I want to do is *push* to the array property.

Is there a better (either shorter or faster) way than this:

```
this.set('arrayProp', this.get('arrayProp').push(element));
```

Also, is there a shortcut for *removing* elements from such an array property?

Answer (score 21):

You are looking for `pushObject`, `removeObject`, etc. See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html.

```
this.get('arrayProp').pushObject(element);
```

For correct behavior by computed properties and observers, it is strongly recommended you use these methods instead of `push` or other native Array methods.